# More elegant way to group objects by nested attribute

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, object, lodash

I am getting the data from a third-party API and cannot filter it beforehand. I have the following array:

```
[
 [
  User1 {
    attr1: 'abc',
    attr2: ['0x1', '0xa']
  },
  User2 {
    attr1: 'def'
    attr2: ['0x1', '0xb']
  }
 ]
 [
  User3 {
    attr1: 'ghi',
    attr2: ['0x1', '0xa']
  },
  User4 {
    attr1: 'jkl',
    attr2: ['0x1', '0xb']
  },
  User5 {
    attr1: 'mno',
    attr2: ['0x1', '0xc']
  } 
 ]
]
```

The goal is to get the following. Essentially, I want to group users based on attr2[1] and filter out users that don't have a pair. The key would be the attr2[1].

```
[
 {
   attr2_1: '0xa',
   attrs: [User1, User3]
 },
 {
   attr2_1: '0xb',
   attrs: [User2, User4]
 }
]
```

I have a working solution but I would like to know how to solve it more elegantly.

I group the users by the second attribute

```
const usersByParam = _.chain(allUsers)
       .flatten()
       .groupBy(user => user.attr2[1])
       .value()
```

I filter the grouped users to remove entries that don't have a pair (User5 in the example)

```
const filteredUsers = _.omitBy(usersByParam, (val) => {return val.length < 2})
```

I go through the filtered results to get my user objects

```
for (const key in filteredUsers) {
  userArray.push({attr2_1: key, attrs: filteredUsers[key]} as User)
}
```

It gives me what I want, but I am sure there are more elegant ways of solving it.

Comment: Your data is invalid JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JavaScript:

```js
const data = [{User1: {attr1: 'abc',attr2: ['0x1', '0xa']}},{User2: {attr1: 'def',attr2: ['0x1', '0xb']}},{User3: {attr1: 'ghi',attr2: ['0x1', '0xa']}},{User4: {attr1: 'jkl',attr2: ['0x1', '0xb']}},{User5: {attr1: 'mno',attr2: ['0x1', '0xc']}}]
const result = Object.entries(
    data.reduce((a, c) => {
      const [k] = Object.keys(c)
      a[c[k].attr2[1]] = [...(a[c[k].attr2[1]] || []), k]
      return a
    }, {})
  )
  .filter(([, users]) => users.length > 1)
  .map(([attr2_1, attrs]) => ({ attr2_1, attrs }))

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

The data that you posted is not valid JSON. So, assuming that it is supposed to be an array of objects, I modified it in my code below to reflect that.

I'm not sure how to do it in lodash, but you can just use vanilla JavaScript to accomplish this. By using the [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) methods, you can manipulate the data to how you need.

See snippet below.

```js
const data = [{
    User1: {
      attr1: 'abc',
      attr2: ['0x1', '0xa']
    }
  },
  {
    User2: {
      attr1: 'def',
      attr2: ['0x1', '0xb']
    }
  },
  {
    User3: {
      attr1: 'ghi',
      attr2: ['0x1', '0xa']
    }
  },
  {
    User4: {
      attr1: 'jkl',
      attr2: ['0x1', '0xb']
    }
  },
  {
    User5: {
      attr1: 'mno',
      attr2: ['0x1', '0xc']
    }
  }
];

const reduced = Object.values(data.reduce((a, c) => {
  var user = Object.keys(c)[0];
  var key = c[user].attr2[1];
  a[key] ??= {};
  a[key].attr2_1 = key;
  a[key].attrs ??= [];
  a[key].attrs.push(user);
  return a;
}, {})).filter(element => element.attrs.length === 2);

console.log(reduced);
```

Comment: Ugh, yes. Good catch.  I have corrected it. Apparently the 'tidy code' button in the snippets doesn't know what the nullish assignment is. It was all working till I clicked on that...

Answer (score 0):

Your code is already elegant, I just replaced the `for ... in` with `map`

```js
const userArray = _.chain(allUsers)
  .flatten()
  .groupBy(user => user.attr2[1])
  .omitBy(val => val.length < 2)
  .map((attrs, attr2_1) => ({ attr2_1, attrs }))
  .value();
```